# Set: Computing Representations of Relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I was given the relation:

$$ p = \{(1,4), (2,1), (2,3), (4,2)\}$$

on the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$

I was then asked to compute the relation $p^3$, which was quite easy, as one only needs to elevate to the three the relation matrix of &p&, and indeed the result is $$p^3 = \{(1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2), (4, 4)\}$$.

However, I was also asked to compute $p^*$, and the solution is $$p^* = \{ (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4) \}$$

Can anyone explain me how to reach the solution for $p^*$ and which matrix operations would I need to perform to arrive there from the relation matrix of $p$?

Comment: Sorry but what is $p^*$ ?

Comment: My guess would be all possible pairs reachable by any $p^n$.

Comment: I can only imagine what is being asked for is the transitive closure.  Using the matrix, you could see it as $p^1+p^2+p^3+p^4$ (*having ended at $p^4$ since the set has just four elements, end at $p^n$ for larger relations*) and interpret the result as an adjacency matrix as well where zeroes remain as zeroes and nonzero numbers indicate a path present (*and indeed, the number itself indicates the number of paths present from a particular starting point to another ending point*)

Comment: MaximilianJanisch It is what JMoravitz and Westenfux described, and it makes sense. zwim, I read that somewhere, but I could not make any sense of it. Many thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well $p^\star = \bigcup_{k\geq 0} p^k$ is the reflexive ($k=0$) and transitive closure of the relation $p$.

Just compute all powers of $p$ starting from $k=0$ until you reach a power $p^k$ that does not increase the set of pairs reached so far, then stop.

Comment: many thanks that is the explanation I needed. Just another question, if you can answer, how do I compute $p^2$, $p^3$ and so one without using a relation matrix? Is that even possible?

Comment: Its possible: if $(a,b),(b,c)\in p$, then $(a,c)\in p^2$.